# C# Sorting Directory.GetFiles() by name without extension

Tags: c#, file, sorting

I'm trying to obtaint a sorted list of the files inside a directory. This files have differentes extensions.

```
foreach (String File in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*").OrderBy(f => f))
{
 stringA[i] = File;
 i++;
}
```

The problem is that the result is not sorted like I expected. This is what I obtein in "stringA":

```
1.txt
10.txt
11.png
12.png
18.png
19.txt
2.txt
21.png
22.png
23.png
24.png
25.txt
26.txt
27.txt
28.txt
29.txt
3.png
30.txt
31.txt
32..png
33..png
34..png
35.png
4.txt
40.txt
41.png etc
```

What I want is : 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.png, 4.txt, 5.png, 6.txt, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11, 19, 20, 21, 29, 30...

What can I do?

Comment: please tag the technology u are using. like `java` `c#` or any one else ??

Comment: C#. Sorry, I forgot about the tags..

Comment: Are the files labelled as numbers like in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called alphanumeric sorting. For custom sorting in general, implement the IComparer interface with a custom compare method that suits your need.

For alphanumeric, Dotnetpearls has an excellent example and implementation here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting.

Copy the AlphanumComparatorFast class, then use it like this:

```
        var list = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        Array.Sort(list, new AlphanumComparatorFast());
```

Comment: Happy to help. If you don't mind, please remember to hit the check mark to the left of the answer to accept it ;-).

Answer (score 2):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*")
         .Select(file => new { FileName = file, FileNumber = long.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))  })
         .OrderBy(data => data.FileNumber);

foreach( file in files )
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} (Number: {1})", file.FileName, FileNumber)
}
```

Please note that this omits any error handling you may need.